# How can I set a notification to let me know when a specific contact goes online in Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to have a notification just for one specific contact, not all of them.

Comment: I think online notification will not be getting but use custom sounds for your contacts so that whenever that person chats with you will come to know

Answer (score -1):

There Is A way in hangouts. Go to options on where you send the messages and press the checkmark by notifications.

Comment: Thanks, is it just for one specific contact, or all of them?